# Apache ignoring file extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I use the following .htaccess code to make my URLs cleaner:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

It basically check if the requested URL points to a file or a directory and if it doesn't, it formats it in a particular way.

The problem is that my production server seems to ignore file extensions when it checks if the requested URL points to a file. For example, it would consider the URL `/contact` pointing to a file named `contact.jpg` if a file with that name existed on the root of the server.

What causes Apache to behave like that and what can I do to control it - make it strict about file extensions?

Answer (score 10):

I believe it's because of MultiViews option.
Try `Options -MultiViews` in the .htaccess

Comment: I thought that, too, at first. It doesn't fix it. I appreciate the answer, though.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed my problem, which took me ages to find the right thing to Google for.

Comment: Fixed for me too +1