# php Apache server url rewrite issue

Tags: php, apache, url

The problem is the following:
There is one server that I deploy to and for some reason the server does not respond to urls as usual. What I mean is when I have a file called `somefile.php` uploaded to `mysite.com/` and I type in browser `mysite.com/somefile` the file `somefile.php` gets called instead of saying 404 not found. I think that this is weird and for some reason it prevents my .htaccess file to rewrite correctly, because the file somefile.php gets called and if there is information after `mysite.com/somefile` like `mysite.com/somefile/someotherfile`, `someotherfile` gets ignored and `somefile.php` gets displayed. I have all other .htaccess files deleted even in parent directories of the server and still the same result. I hope that you can hep me.

On localhost this problem is not observed. I get 404 not found as I should...

Comment: Could this be your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692178/apache-ignoring-file-extensions

Comment: You can also enable the mod_rewrite log and see if it's actually causing your problem. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: Well yes, this seems to be my problem but there is no answer provided and since I have deleted all my htaccess files and I dont believe that they are causing this :(

Comment: So you tried disabling multiviews as well as verified that nothing shows up in a mod_rewrite log file?

Comment: Omg mate i tried Options -MultiViews and it worked perfectly I just thought, Thank you so much :)))) Gues the other person was having some kind of other issue...

Comment: Put it down as an answer so i can mark it.

Comment: Done and done, glad that was the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have **MultiViews** currently enabled. Try disabling them.

> **Multiviews**
>
> MultiViews is a per-directory option, meaning it can be set
>   with an Options directive within a ,  or 
>   section in httpd.conf, or (if AllowOverride is properly set) in
>   .htaccess files. Note that Options All does not set MultiViews; you
>   have to ask for it by name.
>
> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map
>   which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of
>   them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements.
>
> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews